# special character key comes with noname instead of letter on xev

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, locale, ibus, xev

```
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    root 0x269, subw 0x0, time 25839746, (517,242), root:(622,350),
    state 0x0, keycode 254 (keysym 0x11f, (no name)), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    root 0x269, subw 0x0, time 25840405, (517,242), root:(622,350),
    state 0x0, keycode 255 (keysym 0x15f, (no name)), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    root 0x269, subw 0x0, time 25840514, (517,242), root:(622,350),
    state 0x0, keycode 255 (keysym 0x15f, (no name)), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I'm using Linux on dex. Ubuntu 16.0.4.5 LTS. I just need some special characters like şğİı. I did some research on web (for 2 days) with 0 knowledge of Linux but my last stop is here. The problem is when I open `/usr/share/x11/xkb/symbols/tr`--this is the current keyboard layout on my system-- I can see gbreve(ğ),scedilla(ş) etc. Also I tried ibus preferences if my key is recognized by system and it shows 0x11f. Representation of gbreve(ğ) is: **UTF-16**:0x11f **UTF-8**: 0xC4, 0x9F when I pressed it. Also when I type I get this:

```
$ locale -a 
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
tr_CY.utf8
tr_TR.utf8
```

So.. I see it's different utf8 and utf-16 but what can I do to type those letters? I just need it for LibreOffice.

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

---

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
[sudo] password for dextop: 
grep: /proc/bus/input/devices: Permission denied
grep: /proc/bus/input/devices: Permission denied
Your console font configuration will be updated the next time your system
boots. If you want to update it now, run 'setupcon' from a virtual console.
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
insserv: warning: script 'int_container.sh' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'vnc.sh' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'init_container.sh' missing LSB tags and overrides
```

There's no interface like yours when I type that command instead

[image]

I select generic 105 int and select language layouts there. As you mentioned no dead keys and I set up compose to alt gr but that didn't help.

I fixed LSB tag problem on previous Ubuntu img set up. So the problem is not that. Also, I heard some errors are caused by python bugs. For example, I can bring up language select menu but when I click it on system settings nothing comes up. I also tried to change locale tr but it gave me nothing for output. I know Linux on dex is something not reliable to set things up but my aim was just generate couple letters via editing xkb x11 symbols file etc.

Okay, I'm beginning to understand what the actual problem is.

1. `grep: /proc/bus/input/devices: Permission denied` this error hints at something. Need permission. Also I can't change layout in any way. Even if I choose English keyboard it gives me that error. So I can't change anything. So since it's still default English keyboard it says noname in xev output. Because it doesn't exist in EN layout.
2. I searched why it gives me that error. First I saw proc folder is registered as nobody group. So, read only.

First I run same dkpg command with root user. `No protocol specified Cannot open display ":1"update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)` This time it gave 3 additional erorrs.

Then tried `sudo adduser dextop /proc/bus/input/devices` and got
`adduser: The group` /proc/bus/input/devices' does not exist`

Then tried `chown -R dextop /proc/bus/input/devices` this time `chown: changing ownership of '/proc/bus/input/devices': Permission denied`

At this point and according to this https://serverfault.com/questions/60711/chown-operation-not-permitted-for-root
I'm using FAT File system and maybe the Linux image I'm using on Linux dex. It doesn't and will never let me change keyboard layout. Which is funny. But thanks for the effort.

Last edit: problem is Vnc viewer built into Linux in dex app not the img itself. Because I could produce all chars I want when I open Ubuntu in terminal mode and connect to another vnc server. (Connecting to it is not useful btw. connection pauses when you full screen that vnc viewer app)
but I guess I find a way to use LibreOffice with my native language. I explained in reddit, here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/LinuxonDex/comments/fuycwj/the_reason_of_why_i_cant_type_special_characters/

Comment: It's unclear to me what your actual problem is. I just added and switched to the tr keyboard layout, and could easily type e.g. ş and ğ.

Comment: gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
@a(ss) []

Comment: That's odd. You should go to _System Settings -> Text Entry_ and add the layouts - including the Turkish one - you need to be able to access.

Comment: Does dex mean a Samsung DeX handheld device? I think it has a lot of problems and not really recommended. You need a real computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set the keyboard layout to US with no dead key

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

set compose key on your favorite key (on picture, Alt_R)

[image: GUI keyboard shortcuts]

Now type the characters with compose key + combinations

<kbd>Compose</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>g</kbd> = "ǧ"
<kbd>Compose</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> = "ş"
<kbd>Compose</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> = "İ"
<kbd>Compose</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> = "ı"

For other characters, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GtkComposeTable
also https://fsymbols.com/keyboard/linux/compose/

You can also type Unicode characters by <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> hexadecimal code <kbd>Space</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a lot at :) least i can type with hexedecimal codes now :)